# how make an image transperent to a slide show image

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css

I placed an Image over a Jquery slideshow and it's working fine ,but i want image to be semi transperent to the underlined slide show ,also I planned to place a dropdown menu just above the same slide show, which should be also semi transperent to the same....
Kindly help me for the same........................

```
<div id="slideshow">




        <img src="imag/slider-1.jpg" alt="" class="active" height="100%" width="100%"/>
        <img src="imag/slider-2.jpg" alt="" height="100%" width="100%" />
        <img src="imag/slider-3.jpg" alt=""  height="100%" width="100%" />
        <img src="imag/slider-4.jpg" alt=""  height="100%" width="100%" />
        <%--<img src="imag/slider-5.jpg" alt=""  height="100%" width="100%" />
    --%>
    <br />
       <div class="logo">
       <img src="imag/small1.png" alt="" height="100%" width="100% " />

        </div>



    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always use jQuery to fade to the transparency.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

```
.fadeTo('slow', 0.5, function() {
  // Animation complete.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the opacity on an element with css

```
div.logo { opacity: .1; } /* set to 10% opacity */
```